# Count Function in MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access

In a table, I have below columns and same columns will be in Query

```
VIN            Person Number         Base price    
12                ABC                100    
36                ABC                200
71                DEF                100
44                ABC                500
66                698                300
etc               etc                etc
```

New column (Col 4) is for Incentive, if Person number is more than 2 then .4% of base price to be applied and if 2 and less it is .3%. How do I build this in query.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Count function to count how often a person number appears.
I'd suggest to use a separate discount table to store discount percentages.
This way, you can keep your discount percentages flexible and stay away from hard coding.

```
SELECT x.VIN, x.[Person Number], x.[Base Price], 
IIF((SELECT Count([Person Number]) FROM yourtable WHERE [Person Number] = x.[Person Number]) >=2, x.[Base Price]*0.96, x.[Base Price]*0.98) AS NettPrice
FROM yourtable AS x;
```